# Continued Fractional representation of irrational numbers

Tags: continued-fractions

I know that any rational number can be expressed as a continued fraction, but what about irrational numbers? For example, what is the continued fractional representation of Pi, or e for that matter? Can all real numbers be expressed as continued fractions? For example, can the following number be expressed as a continued fraction?

0.1234567891011121314...

Comment: From the second paragraph of [the Wikipedia article on continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction): "*every irrational number $\alpha$ is the value of a unique infinite continued fraction...*" (which, combined with the fact that every rational number can be expressed as a continued fraction, means that **all** real numbers can).

Comment: In fact, $\pi$ has a [very nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Continued_fractions) continued fraction decomposition.

Comment: Every real number has a representation as a **simple continued fraction**. For irrationals the expression is unique.

Answer (score 1):

All real numbers can be expressed (not necessarily uniquely) as continued fractions. Check out the Wikipedia article on the subject, in particular from [this point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansions_of_.CF.80) on down for the special examples you requested.